# Ruby Decimal Fractions

Tags: ruby, function

I am completly new to both programming and this forum. Today I wrote my very first script, and it works so far:

```
 def deltay(y2, y1)
  #puts "Delta y=#{y2 - y1}"
  y2 - y1
end

def deltax(x2, x1)
  #puts "Delta x=#{x2- x1}"
  x2-x1
end

def m(vardeltay, vardeltax)
  #puts "m=#{vardeltay / vardeltax}"
  vardeltay / vardeltax
end

def n(gradient, varx, vary)
 vary-gradient*varx
end

#activate the lines 21-25, when n is given.
#puts "Welcome to my linear function script. Please start with telling me your n:"

#print "> " ; n=STDIN.gets.to_i

#puts "So your n is #{n}."


puts "The first thing I need is your m.Please input your y2 then press RETURN and enter your y1:"
print "> " ; vary2=STDIN.gets.to_i ; vary1=STDIN.gets.to_i ; deltay(vary2, vary1) 

puts "Now, please input your x2 then press RETURN and enter your x1:"
print "> " ; varx2=STDIN.gets.to_i ; varx1=STDIN.gets.to_i ; deltax(varx2, varx1)

puts "\n"

puts "Your m equals #{m(deltay(vary2, vary1), deltax(varx2, varx1))}"

varm=m(deltay(vary2, vary1), deltax(varx2, varx1))

puts "So, now we need n. Your current equalation looks like this:y=#{varm}m+n"
puts "Lets insert your point, you gave me earlier : P(#{varx2}, #{vary2})"
puts "So, that is:"
puts "#{vary2}=#{varm*varx2}+n \nNow we going to perform |-#{varm*varx2}. And that equals #{n(varm, varx2, vary2)}"  ; n=n(varm, varx2, vary2) #{#{vary2-(varm*varx2)}=n" ; n=vary2-(varm*varx2)}

puts "So this is our equation so far:"
puts "f(x)=#{varm}x+#{n}"

puts "Now let's get to y, okay? So I need a value for x:"
print "> " ; varx=STDIN.gets.to_i ; puts "y=#{varm*varx+n}"
```

The problem is, if I insert negative integers(-1)/decimal fractions (1,2) for y2,y1,x2 or x1, it won't work correctly. Maybe my question is really stupid, but I didn't find anything helping my problem on the net.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please define why this code doesn't work correctly. Provide your input, your desired output and the *wrong* output to have better understanding of your needs. Otherwise, the question would be closed as unclear or as off topic.

Comment: Define "won't work correctly".

Comment: I thought I made it clear. Well for example, when you give him y2=1,2; or y2=-3. Even if only one integer has "," or is negative, the script won't work: [http://puu.sh/biFO9/8ea61c593f.png]
Also, I just noticed it wont work when (x2-x1)>(y2-y1).

@Define "won't work correctly".
 Well, m will be calculated false, and therefore the whole equaltion get's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are at least two problems in your code:

1. You are parsing numbers using `to_i`. This method only returns integers ("to integer") and any fractional part is cut off. You can use `to_f` instead. (Or `to_d` if you decide to use BigDecimal instead of floating point numbers)
2. It looks like you input decimal numbers using a comma (,) as decimal separator. You have to use a dot (.) instead.

PS: It helps if you tidy up your code a little bit. The mixing of calculations and string interpolations makes understanding the code unnecessarily hard. Same goes for putting multiple statements in a single line...

For example, this is hard to read, especially if you don't have smart syntax highlighting:

```
puts "Your m equals #{m(deltay(vary2, vary1), deltax(varx2, varx1))}"
```

This is better:

```
value_of_m = m(deltay(vary2, vary1), deltax(varx2, varx1))
puts "Your m equals #{value_of_m}"
```

Comment: Thank you really much, did work. Yes, I agree, it's pretty untidy, as I did it in a rush. I made it when I got home and I got like one hour before I had to go again. Also the language is originally german.

I just don't get the part with "mixing of calculations and string iterpolations" what excactly do you mean, can you give an example please?